# Contextual Menu item method swizzling

Tags: macos, methods, finder

Any idea how do I handle contextual menu click inside finder via method swizzling ? I am trying to find which method needs to be overridden from Finder.h for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this sample which shows how to add the items using method swizzling and code injection.

https://github.com/infinitelabs/FinderMenu

> Adds submenu to the context menu of Mac OS X Finder. Submenu has two items, clicking on them the window with the selected items is displayed.

It uses https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject to update the Finder process. Seems like it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gdb` and set breakpoints on objective-c messages. You can also use `instrument` tool for finding method names.